# Abstract Linear Transformation: Check whether it is injective and surjective or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $M: \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a linear trasnformation defined as $M(T) = S_T$ where $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $S_T$ is the standard matrix for T (applying T in each vector of the respective standard basis).

How do I verify whether M is injective or not? How about M being surjective?

I know that a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ is injective

- iff $\{v \in V; Tv = 0\} = \{0\}$
- iff $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is linear independent then $\{Tv_1, ..., Tv_n\}$ is linear independent.

But I don't see how to apply those facts to that kind of verifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injectivity will indeed suffice since the two vector spaces have the same dimension. Your question is essentially now how to show that the matrix representation for a linear transformation is well defined, in the sense that the same matrix representation implies the same linear transformation.

to do this, choose a basis $\{e_1\dots e_n\}$, and note that a matrix representation is nothing but a specification $e_i \mapsto a_{i1}+\dots+a_{im}$.

a quick lemma would be that
$$T(e_i)=0, \forall i \in \{1, \dots  n\} \implies T=0$$

This can be proven by rank nullity and noting that $\{e_i\}$ constitute a basis for the kernel.

From this, the result follows readily by checking that if 
$A(e_i)=B(e_i)$ for all $i$, then we have by linearity that
$$(A-B)e_i=0$$
for all $i$, in which case we can apply the lemma, which implies the result.

Comment: Is the following right? Pick two transformations $T_1$ and $T_2$ in the aforementioned space such that $M(T_1) = M(T_2)$. Thus, $M(T_1) - M(T_2) = 0 \iff M(T_1 - T_2) = 0 \implies T_1 - T_2 = 0 \iff T_1 = T_2$.

Comment: That's good , but the crux of the argument is in the  implication $(M(T_1-T_2)=0 \implies T_1-T_2=0)$. Make sure to use the fact that if a linear transformation vanishes on basis elements, it is the zero transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ have same dimension $m \times n$, checking that $\ker M = \{T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \mid M(T) = O \} = \{0\}$ suffices.

Suppose that $M(T) = O$.  Then $Te_j = \mathbf{0}$ for all $1 \le j \le n$.  Since $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ (i.e. $T$ is linear), $T \equiv 0$ (i.e. $T$ is the zero transformation).  This proves the injectivity of $M$.

Comment: I don`t see how this proves that the zero thansformation is the only element in the kernel of $M$. Is zero transformation the only linear transformation such that $Te_j = 0$ for all $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$?

Comment: @Daniel $M(T) = O$ means that the transformation matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the standard matrix is zero.  i.e "applying $T$ in each vector $e_j$ of the respective standard basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$" gives $n$ zero column vectors in $\Bbb{R}^m$.

Comment: I've understood that. My concerning is on the part $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{m}) \; \textrm{and} \; M(T) = 0 \implies M$ is injective. I have the impression that something is missing in your proof.

Comment: @Daniel The argument $M(T) = 0$ implies $T=0$ shows that $M$ is injective is standard since $M$ is linear.